# Using a m:n table in EDMX (EF 4.3) without associating it with related tables

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, edmx

I have a horribly designed DB where TableA maps to Table B, C, D via m:n mapping table.

When I incldue the map table in the EDMX I get a runtime error that the entite's key columns do not match the table's key columns. Error 3002: ........

I have found no way to avoid this, even when taking out the extra column in the EDMX model. When I do that, I get other errors about multiplicity having to be 1.

**In fact, the DB cannot and must not be altered.**

**So, is there a way to display the m:n mapping table in the EDMX without associations?
I am asking because the mapping table is not "visible" as a table but as an association (in the designer there's a line between two other tables.**

Comment: Yes, EF is smart to map pure join tables into associations only. Maybe in your case, you can start with an edmx that only has the mapping table, modify it as you see fit and then add the other tables.

Answer (score 1):

While there's likely a better way, what Gert said is what I'd recommend:

- make a copy of the database (at least the schema)
- add a column to the mapping table
- update the edmx based on that version (the extra column will mean the table will be included as 'real'
- drop extra column from edmx

Another alternative that might work (haven't tried it before)

- update model to include just the mapping table (make sure it doesn't include the other 2 tables first, at least not both of them)
- this should make it a 'real table' in the model
- update model to include the other table(s)

You can always create/map manually, but hopefully one of the above is faster/easier than doing so. :)